# TouchableOpacity not working on android - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, touchableopacity, touchablehighlight

I facing some problem with TouchableOpacity...it works perfectly on ios but not android.
I'm very sure that i import from "react-native"  Not "react-native-gesture-handler".

Then i change to use TouchableHighlight from "react-native-gesture-handler" , remove the one from react-native and its works. But still TouchableOpacity cannot be use either from "react-native" or "react-native-gesture-handler".

I never put both "react-native" or "react-native-gesture-handler" at the same time because every time i try to change i will comment out one of them

I'm stuck now because other screen works perfectly.

It only happen in this modal screen (below). Can anybody please advice me?

tq

```
      <Modal
        visible={cameraVisible}
        animationType="slide"
        style={styles.modal}
        transparent={false}
      >
        <SafeAreaView>
          <Button title="Close" onPress={() => setCameraVisible(false)} />
        </SafeAreaView>
        <Camera
          style={styles.camera}
          type={type}
          ref={(r) => {
            camera = r;
          }}
        />

        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            width: screenWidth,
            height: 60,
            backgroundColor: "white",
            justifyContent: "space-around",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              setType(
                type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                  ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                  : Camera.Constants.Type.back
              );
            }}
          >
            <Icon name={"camera-retake"} size={40} color="#076bf7" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => _takePicture(cameraId1)}>
            <Icon name={"camera-iris"} size={40} color="#076bf7" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Modal>
```

Comment: I've found that most of the reason buttons often dont seem to work on android is due to view clipping or one view being on top of the other. I use the good ole art of color debugging the ui, go through each View/TouchableOpacity and set the background color to something obvious eg red, blue, green and look for either a TouchableOpacity that's out of it's bounds or behind another View

Comment: tried...but still stuck on android...